# Prove that a function satisfies the equation given a change of variables. (use of chain rule)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $ C ^ 1 $ such that:

\begin{align} 3x^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) +2y^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=3(f(x,y))^2\end{align}

Consider changing variables:

\begin{align} u(x,y)=x , v(x,y)= \frac{1}{3x}-\frac{1}{2y}\end{align}

and let's define the function $g(u,v)=$. Prove that f satisfies the equation:

\begin{align} u^2\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} (u,v) = (g(u,v))^2. \forall (u,v) \in dom(g)\end{align}

So far the only thing I can think of is:

\begin{align} 
u(x,y)=x \Rightarrow x(u,v)=u\\
v(x,y)= \frac{1}{3x}-\frac{1}{2y} \Rightarrow y(u,v)=\frac{3u}{2-6u}
\end{align}

I really don't understand how to go on, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Set $z=f(x,y)$. From chain rule: $$z_x=z_uu_x+z_vv_x$$ $$z_y=z_uu_y+z_vv_y$$ This becomes $$z_x=z_u-\frac{z_v}{3x^2}$$ $$z_y=\frac{z_v}{2y^2}$$ Plugging into our original PDE yields $$3x^2\Big(z_u-\frac{z_v}{3x^2}\Big)+2y^2\Big(\frac{z_v}{2y^2}\Big)=z^2$$ This simplifies to $$3x^2z_u=z^2$$ which is equivalent to $$3u^2z_u=z^2$$ The solution to the aforementioned PDE is $$z=\frac{3u}{k(v)u+1}$$ where $k$ is a differentiable function of a real variable. Back substitution gives the solution to our original equation: $$z=\frac{3x}{k\Big(\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{1}{2y}\Big)x+1}$$